# sumar minutos despues de 300 segundos

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un cronómetro, que después de 300 segundos, es cuando empiece a contar minutos completos. Pero pasan los 300 segundos, y no me cambia los minutos, como debería. Adjunto mi código actual:

```
cronometro = setInterval(function (){
        contadorSegundos = sec++;
        if(contadorSegundos == 300){
           sec = 0;
           min = 5
           minutos.innerHTML = min;

           if(sec == 60){
             min++;
             minutos.innerHTML = min;
             console.log(min);
           }
         }
 }, 1000);
```

Creo que me lógica está bien, pero obviamente algo falla... Lo que yo había pensado es que, cuando contadorSegundos sea igual a 300 pon 5 en el span de los minutos... Dentro de ese bloque de los 300 segundos, ponemos los segundos a 0 y cada vez que llegue a 60 aumente los minutos y me vaya sustituyendo los 5 Min por el valor que corresponda, pero nunca me hace ese segundo inner

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Has intentado enves de contadorSegundos == 300 contadorSegundos >= 300 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El incremento de los minutos debe ir afuera del `if(contadorSegundos == 300)`. Y como se quieren incrementar solamente después de pasados 300 segundos se puede agregar una condición adicional:

```
let contadorSegundos = 0;
let sec = 0;
let min = 0;
let contarMinutos = false;

cronometro = setInterval(function (){
        contadorSegundos = sec++;
        if(contadorSegundos == 300){
           sec = 0;
           min = 5;
           minutos.innerHTML = min;
           contarMinutos = true;
         }
         
         // incrementar minutos después de 300 segundos
         if(contarMinutos &&  sec == 60){
             min++;
             sec = 0;
             minutos.innerHTML = min;
             console.log(min);
           }
         
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: Lo primero gracias por tu respuesta @Lobos Pero cuando pasa de los 5min, no aumenta los minutos, es decir, ni muestra el console.log(min) ni hace el innerHTML de los minutos a 6 por ejemplo y es justo lo que necesito, que empiece a contar minutos a partir del 5

Comment: Ya actualicé. Agregué una variable que sirve para saber si se debe contar en minutos.

Answer (score 0):

Al segundo if solo entra si contadorSegundos = 300, la variable sec queda en 0, min queda en 5 y nunca vas a entrar al siguiente if. Te dejo un código que podría funcionar, espero te sirva

```js
sec = 0;
min = 0;
cronometro = setInterval(function (){
        contadorSegundos = sec++;      
        if(contadorSegundos >= 60){
          if(min < 5){
           min = 5
           //min.innerHTML = min;
          }else{
            if((contadorSegundos%60) ==0 ){
             min++;
             //minutos.innerHTML = min;
            }
          }          
        }
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: Lo primero gracias por tu respuesta @Tomas pero necesito esos 300 porque son los 5 min que despues de estos, es cuando necesito que mi cronometro empiece a contar tiempo ya que es para medir una asistencia... A parte, necesito hacer un innerhtml o un append a mi html para ir mostrando el tiempo no veo que en tu código se haga eso. De nuevo, gracias por tu tiempo